# Error when installing pyminizip on docker

Tags: python, docker

I am getting an error while installing `pyminizip` package inside docker container ( docker version 17.03.1-ce). I am doing it inside virtual environment with python 2.7.13.

I ended up with below message while trying to install it.

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Isrc -Izlib123 -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c src/py_minizip.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/py_minizip.o
    src/py_minizip.c: In function ‘_compress’:
    src/py_minizip.c:251: warning: ‘filepathnameinzip’ may be used uninitialized in this function
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Isrc -Izlib123 -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c src/zip.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/zip.o
    In file included from src/zip.c:66:
    src/crypt.h:34: error: redefinition of typedef ‘z_crc_t’
    src/zip.h:83: note: previous declaration of ‘z_crc_t’ was here
    src/zip.c:201: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    src/zip.c:203: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Is there any alternate of pyminizip package ?

I want to create a password protected zip. So, even if there is any alternate solution to it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. It is working fine with pyminizip version  0.2.1. I had faced this issue on 0.2.2 and 
0.2.3 but version 0.2.1 is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Would be useful know what docker image you use... but Try to Install python developer version:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

and libevent libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: These commands works with ubuntu based container which again required installation of gcc. But I am facing this issue on container with cent OS 6.9. I tried same command "yum install install python-devel" and "yum install libevent-devel" but getting same output.

Comment: you can share the Dockerfile?